# How to change title of list item programatically using Custom Action with JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a custom action on item list menu called `Change Status` as shown in the picture [image]

I have created this `Custom Action` using the following javascript code:

```
 function AddCustomUserActionToECB() {  
    //Get the client context,web and list object   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web(); 
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('helpdesk');
    var userCustomActionColl = oList.get_userCustomActions();  
    var oUserCustomAction = userCustomActionColl.add();  
    oUserCustomAction.set_location('EditControlBlock');  
    oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100);  
    oUserCustomAction.set_title("Change Status"); 


     oUserCustomAction.set_url("/helpdesk/Lists/helpdesk/EditForm.aspx?ID={ItemId}"); 


        oUserCustomAction.update();          
        clientContext.load(userCustomActionColl);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
    }  

    function QuerySuccess() {  
        console.log("Custom Action added to ECB menu.");  
    }  

    function QueryFailure() {  
        console.log('Request failed - ' + args.get_message());  
    }
```

But I can only go to the edit mode of that item. But what I want is when we click at `Change Status` to automatically change the `Title` field to `AutoGenerated`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `oUserCustomAction.set_url("/helpdesk/Lists/helpdesk/EditForm.aspx?ID={ItemId}");` try to use in your code `UserCustomAction.set_scriptBlock(UPDATE_ITEM_SCRIPT_TEXT)`. And write code to update item `Title`.

Comment: Do I have to call a method inside the script block or write the entire script inside `UserCustomAction.set_scriptBlock( Update Code Here )`?